# Submit form with array of values with same name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm creating a recipe application in Laravel and each recipe is going to have an undetermined amount of ingredients. The user is going to be able to click a button to dynamically add additional amount, measure and ingredients fields. For now I just have 3 fields for testing. The ingredient and measure select boxes are being populated from their own database tables with their ids as values. This is what I have so far.

**View w/Form**

```
              <form action="store">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                    <div class="row">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Add Recipe</button>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <label for="recipe_name">Recipe Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="recipe_name" class="form-control input-sm" id="recipe_name">
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                            <label for="recipe_desc">Recipe Description</label>
                            <input type="text" name="recipe_desc" class="form-control input-sm" id="recipe_desc">
                        </div>
                        <br />
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <label for="amount">Amount</label>
                        <input type="number" name="amount[]" class="form-control input-sm" id="amount" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <label for="measure">Measure</label>
                        {!! Form::select('measure[]', 
                            (['0' => 'Measure'] + $measure), null, 
                            ['class' => 'form-control input-sm', 'id' => 'measure']) !!}
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <label for="ingredient">Ingredient</label>
                        {!! Form::select('ingredient[]', 
                            (['0' => 'Select Ingredient'] + $ingredients), null, 
                            ['class' => 'form-control input-sm', 'id' => 'ingredient']) !!}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <label for="amount">Amount</label>
                        <input type="number" name="amount[]" class="form-control input-sm" id="amount" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <label for="measure">Measure</label>
                        {!! Form::select('measure[]', 
                            (['0' => 'Measure'] + $measure), null, 
                            ['class' => 'form-control input-sm', 'id' => 'measure']) !!}
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <label for="ingredient">Ingredient</label>
                        {!! Form::select('ingredient[]', 
                            (['0' => 'Select Ingredient'] + $ingredients), null, 
                            ['class' => 'form-control input-sm', 'id' => 'ingredient']) !!}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <label for="amount">Amount</label>
                        <input type="number" name="amount[]" class="form-control input-sm" id="amount" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <label for="measure">Measure</label>
                        {!! Form::select('measure[]', 
                            (['0' => 'Measure'] + $measure), null, 
                            ['class' => 'form-control input-sm', 'id' => 'measure']) !!}
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <label for="ingredient">Ingredient</label>
                        {!! Form::select('ingredient[]', 
                            (['0' => 'Select Ingredient'] + $ingredients), null, 
                            ['class' => 'form-control input-sm', 'id' => 'ingredient']) !!}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                            <label for="recipe_instruct">Recipe Description</label>
                            <textarea rows="3" name="recipe_instruct" class="form-control input-sm" id="recipe_instruct"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

**RecipeController**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $recipeName = $request->input('recipe_name');
    $recipeDesc = $request->input('recipe_desc');
    $recipeInstruct = $request->input('recipe_instruct');
    $ingredients = $request->input('ingredient');

    $id = DB::table('recipe')->insertGetId([
        'name'          => $recipeName,
        'description'   => $recipeDesc,
        'instructions'  => $recipeInstruct
        ]);

    foreach($ingredients as $ingredient)

    DB::table('recipe_ingredient')->insert([??????]);
}
```

If I do a dd it outputs this which is right

```
    array:7 [▼
  "_token" => "DmAHXPc2VxibzbJTDlmSRxcS6XZPTq906IKbz6Hf"
  "recipe_name" => "Test Recipe"
  "recipe_desc" => "Test Recipe Description"
  "amount" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "2"
    2 => "3"
  ]
  "measure" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "8"
    1 => "9"
    2 => "8"
  ]
  "ingredient" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "4"
    1 => "3"
    2 => "7"
  ]
  "recipe_instruct" => "Test recipe instructions"
]
```

I am inserting the recipe_name, recipe_desc and recipe_instruct in the recipe database and returning the id. I am then using that id to reference the ingredient id, measure id and amount id in a recipe_ingredient table.

Do I need to loop through each array to insert them into the recipe_ingredient table seperately? Or is there an easier, more eloquent way of doing that in one shot?

**RecipeIngredient Table**

```
 Schema::create('recipe_ingredient', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('recipe_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('ingredient_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('measure_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('amount');

        $table->foreign('recipe_id')->references('id')->on('recipe')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('ingredient_id')->references('id')->on('ingredient')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('measure_id')->references('id')->on('measure')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Recipe Model**

```
 public function ingredients()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\RecipeIngredient');
}
```

**RecipeIngredient Model**

```
 public function recipe()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Recipe');
}
```

Comment: The more eloquent way of doing that would be to create a Recipe model, and an Ingredient model, defining a relationship between the two and then doing `$recipe->ingredients()->saveMany($ingredients)`.

Comment: I can't comment about Laravel usage, but with prepared statements you could use your foreach loop to build a token based SQL with an incrementing prefix or suffix for each "row" and bind your data accordingly.

Comment: @JohnBupit I already have a one to many relationship from my recipe table to my recipe_ingredients table. It already has fk's to ingredient, measure and amount.

Comment: Yes, but do you have Eloquent models?

Comment: Recipe Model: yes public function ingredients()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\RecipeIngredient');
    }    RedipeIngredient Model:   public function recipe()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Recipe');
    }

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution. Maybe not the right way to do it but it works.

**RecipeController**

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $recipeName = $request->input('recipe_name');
    $recipeDesc = $request->input('recipe_desc');
    $recipeInstruct = $request->input('recipe_instruct');
    $ingredients = $request->input('ingredient');
    $measure = $request->input('measure');
    $amount = $request->input('amount');

    $id = DB::table('recipe')->insertGetId([
        'name'          => $recipeName,
        'description'   => $recipeDesc,
        'instructions'  => $recipeInstruct
        ]);

    $i = 0;

  foreach($ingredients as $ingredient) 
  {

    DB::table('recipe_ingredient')->insert(
        ['recipe_id' => $id, 'ingredient_id' => $ingredients[$i], 'measure_id' => $measure[$i], 'amount' =>$amount[$i]]
    );

    $i++;
  }

  return "Success!";
```